# Prometheus Federation give EOF

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have a 2 cluster platform. Each cluster has a Prometheus scraping metrics. I would like to federate each Prometheus to the other so Prometheus is "hot - hot".

I am following the [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/).

If I click on the federated target `https://prometheus-cluster-1/federate?match%5B%5D=%7Bjob%3D%22kafka1%22%7D` it opens in a browser tab in a instant with all the metrics complete. However the scrape job, on the non federated side, shows state "DOWN" Error EOF.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Federation is not intended to transfer all metrics, and if you try to do so you'll eventually run into problems.Instead, aggregate up the metrics you want and then federate only those.  You also need to modify the scrap config and job level series accordingly. Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62982221/19230181) by Chen A.

Comment: Sometimes this might be due to network connectivity issues.Check firewall rules allow traffic on Prometheus ports.Check this similar Prometheus [Github issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/2459#issuecomment-448393103) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this.

The cross DC federation is going through a loadbalancer which is enforcing https.

The fix is to add TLS config to the federated scrape:

```
- job_name: job1-federated
  tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  scheme: https
```

BTW the federation of kafka metrics (approx 1.2Mb) is < 500ms.